# How to select multiple rows in QTableView using selectionModel

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qtableview, selectionmodel

With:

```
tableView = QTableView()
rows = [0, 1, 2]
```

`tableView.selectRow(0)` or `tableView.selectRow(2)` won't work in this situation since `selectRow()` selects only single row deselecting all others.

There is `selectionModel().select()` method available. But it accepts `QSelectionItem`s object as the argument. How do we declare the `QSelectionItem` object having the row numbers?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should set the selection mode.

```
tableView->setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView::MultiSelection);
```

Comment: Thanks! With the selection mode set to `MultiSelection` what command needs to be used to select row 0 and row 2 so both rows are selected at the same?

Comment: It depends on how you implement. The user will be able to select both at the same time. Try tableView->setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView::SelectItems);

Comment: Thanks again! I would like to know how to select multiple items in QTableView from inside of function (code) (not from the user interaction). Sorry for not being clear.

Answer (score 5):

The code creates a `QTableView` and `QPushButton`. Pressing the button selects the indexes in continuous order (from `index1` to `index2`. It is still an unswered question if it would be possible to select the indexes in any order.

[image]

```
def clicked():
    tableView.setFocus()
    selectionModel = tableView.selectionModel()
    index1 = tableView.model().index(0, 0)
    index2 = tableView.model().index(1, 2)
    itemSelection = QtGui.QItemSelection(index1, index2)
    selectionModel.select(itemSelection, QtGui.QItemSelectionModel.Rows | QtGui.QItemSelectionModel.Select)

app = QtGui.QApplication([])
window = QtGui.QWidget()
window.resize(400, 300)
tableView = QtGui.QTableView()

model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel(4, 2)
for row in range(0, 4):
    for column in range(0, 3):
        item = QtGui.QStandardItem("%s , %s"%(row, column))
        model.setItem(row, column, item)

tableView.setModel(model)

selectionModel = QtGui.QItemSelectionModel(model)
tableView.setSelectionModel(selectionModel)

button = QtGui.QPushButton('Select from 0,0 to 1,2')
button.clicked.connect(clicked)
layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
layout.addWidget(tableView)
layout.addWidget(button)
window.setLayout(layout)
window.show()

app.exec_()
```

Comment: very well explained!

Answer (score 2):

`select()` can also accept an index (and a mode of *select rows*), so you can do this:

```
rows = [1,2,3]
indexes = [model.index(r, 0) for r in rows]
mode = QtCore.QItemSelectionModel.Select | QtCore.QItemSelectionModel.Rows
[tableView.selectionModel().select(index, mode) for i in indexes]
```